# Meaning of "parse-(type1|type2)" under the plugin-includes header of the nutch-site.xml file

Tags: nutch

In `nutch-site.xml`, under `plugin-includes` header, when I write `parse-(type1|type2)`, what does it mean?

Does this mean for each url being fetched by nutch, nutch parses the content first by using `type`1 parser and then sequentially invokes the `type2` parser?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct. This is how it works. But keep in mind that each plugin can be assigned a certain content type, or a set of content types. For example the parse-pdf plugin will not parse msword documents.